# Passing cell.value from a range to another sub

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

I have the following code:

```vb
Dim WS1, WS2 As Worksheet
Dim chatRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim txt As String
    
Sub NameTest()
    
    Set WS1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Page 1")
    Set WS2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    x = 2
    lRow1 = WS1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set chatRange = WS1.Range("B" & x, "B" & lRow1)
    
    For Each cell In chatRange
        If cell.Offset(0, 11).Value = "Accepted" Then
            txt = cell.Offset(0, 18).Value
            NameSplit
        End If
    Next cell
    
End Sub

Sub NameSplit()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FullName As Variant
    Dim x As String, cell As Range
    Dim lRow2 As Long

    FullName = RemoveBlankLines(Split(txt, vbLf))
    lRow2 = WS2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    WS2.Cells(lRow2, 1).Value = cell.Value                 '<===================
    WS2.Cells(lRow2, 2).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value    '<===================
    WS2.Cells(lRow2, 3).Value = cell.Offset(0, 6).Value    '<===================
    WS2.Cells(lRow2, 4).Value = cell.Offset(0, 18).Value   '<===================
End Sub
```

This is part of a test code to read one sheet and then pass the information to another sheet.

I want to use the information from the 'cell' in the range that was set in the first sub to transfer details in the second sub. It works with WS1 & WS2 being declared at the top but it doesn't do the same for the ranges.

The four lines that have arrows is the part I'm struggling with. `cell.value` comes back with:

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

I know the best way would be to have it all in one sub but I would like to keep it separate if at all possible.

Comment: You declared `cell` as range (a second time in the NameSplit function), but never set it. That's the reason you are getting the error at least.. I`ll try to fix your code and post as answer.

Comment: You need to pass `cell` as a range parameter to your `Namesplit` sub.

Comment: Side note: Your `WS1` variable is a `Variant`, your line should look like this: `Dim WS1 as Worksheet, WS2 as Worksheet`

Comment: If these macro's are part of the same module, you can use `Public` variables to make what you declared passed on to your other macro. Also beware, cell can easily be confused with cells!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use `Option Explicit`, though in this case it wouldn't have highlighted the problem.

As said before, you declared `cell` as range (a second time in the NameSplit function), but never set it. That's the reason you are getting the error at least..

As others mentioned, you can pass these values easily into your other sub if you declare them first. See sample (untested) code, based on yours:

```
Option Explicit
'Use global variables only if really needed, but was a good try.

Sub NameTest()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim chatRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim txt As String

    Set WS1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Page 1")
    Set WS2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    x = 2

    lRow1 = WS1.Cells(WS1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row

    Set chatRange = WS1.Range("B" & x, "B" & lRow1)

    For Each cell In chatRange
        If cell.Offset(0, 11).Value = "Accepted" Then
            txt = cell.Offset(0, 18).Value
            Call NameSplit(WS2, cell, txt)
        End If

    Next cell

End Sub

Sub NameSplit(wsDest As Worksheet, rngCell As Range, strTxt As String)    'You can pass any objects through. By default they are passed ByRef (search for ByRef vs ByVal)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FullName As Variant
    Dim x As String
    Dim lRow2 As Long

    FullName = RemoveBlankLines(Split(strTxt, vbLf))
    lRow2 = WS2.Cells(WS2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row + 1

    wsDest.Cells(lRow2, 1).Value = rngCell.Value
    wsDest.Cells(lRow2, 2).Value = rngCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    wsDest.Cells(lRow2, 3).Value = rngCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
    wsDest.Cells(lRow2, 4).Value = rngCell.Offset(0, 18).Value
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Fully qualified `Rows.Count` to `WS1.Rows.Count` and respectively `WS2.Rows.Count` to prevent errors, and correction to the default value in the comment. (thanks @chris neilsen for pointing out).

Comment: I'm still learning and it can be frustrating sometimes, thank you for taking the time to answer. works perfectly.

Comment: I've seen a lot worse code from a beginner, I would say you are on the right track! Keep up, good work.

Comment: Default parameter passing is actually `ByRef` in VBA.  [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sub-statement)

Comment: There is a unqualified Cell reference that might cause errors. `WS2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2)` should be `WS2.Cells(WS2.Rows.Count, 2)`

Comment: Thanks @chrisneilsen for the correction, I've updated the answer. @madmiddle, the lesson from Chris's mention is that you should always qualify your references, otherwise this: `WS2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2)` is the equivalent of `WS2.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Your `NameSplit()` procedure should be declared like so:

```
Sub NameSplit(WS2 as Worksheet, cell as Range)
'
'
'your code here
'
'
End Sub
```

And it should be called like so:

```
call NameSplit(WS2, cell)
```

You can delete `cell as Range` from you declarations in `NameSplit()`

Comment: Don't use the obsolete `Call` statement.  Should be just `NameSplit cell`

Comment: @chris neilsen: why? This is only a matter of taste.

Comment: I find statements much more readable using `Call function(arg1, arg2, arg3, etc)` than `function arg1, arg2, arg3, etc`. Also it stands out in the code that is actually calling an external function/sub.

Comment: I wouldn't call the `Call` statement obsolete. It's usefull if one wants to use parentheses without changing the `ByRef`/ `ByVal` behaviour of `Sub`s

Comment: I find the `Call` usefull because a call to a Sub for me is like a call of a void function. Or a call to a function where I am not interested in the return value.